# Java polygons and Area

Tags: java, awt, polygon, java-2d, area

[image]

Ok so I have a number of polygons (outlined in white in the image).

In an attempt to add all the polygons together so that I get one polygon, which is the outer bounds of all of them, I have converted each Polygon (java class) to an Area(java class) and then added the areas together with the add(Area a) method provided by the Area class.

From there I converted the area back to a polygon and drew it as a filled Polygon (the purple area in the image).

This however is not what I was expecting. Can anyone think of a was where I can do this correctly, or at least just add the triangle area to my polygon?

When I just draw all the separate polygons with a fill I get what I want (drawn) but I need a Polygon representation of it.

[image: What I want]

Comment: Might you be colorblind?  That doesn't look purple to me!  Also, if that wasn't what you were expecting, what _were_ you expecting?

Comment: I wasn't expecting what appears in the first image (top one). I WAS expecting the second image (bottom one, without the triangle gap in the middle that appears in the top one).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Could be a winding issue...unfortunately that's about all I can say :P

Comment: What happens if you fill the added Area? (before converting back to polygon)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to use [JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts). Just create your geometries you want to combine and use the [union](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#union(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)) method. Afterwards you can use the new geometry and paint it using your previous code. Simple code example for union:

```
// build polygon p1
Polygon p1 = new GeometryFactory().createPolygon(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(0,0), new Coordinate(0,10), new Coordinate(10,10), new Coordinate(10,0), new Coordinate(0,0)});
// build polygon p2
Polygon p2 = new GeometryFactory().createPolygon(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(0,0), new Coordinate(0,30), new Coordinate(5,30), new Coordinate(5,0), new Coordinate(0,0)});
// calculate polygon3 as the union of p1 and p2
Polygon p3 = (Polygon) p1.union(p2);
// print simple WKT
System.out.println(p3.toText());
```

Output in this case is (like expected):

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 0 30, 5 30, 5 10, 10 10, 10 0, 5 0, 0 0))
```